# Traverse a graph, but only n levels deep

Tags: java, graph

I have a graph which is essentially an ArrayList of Nodes, each of which stores their neighbors.

```
public class Node {
    ArrayList<Node> neighbors;
    String data;
    public Node() {
        data = null;
        neighbors = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }
}
```

I print out every path in this graph, but only do it n-levels deep. How should I go about coding this?

Or, if I should store this differently, feel free to let me know. But more importantly I want to know how to print out every path n-levels deep.

Comment: Can you print all paths all the way? Could you show us your code that does it?

Comment: Is there a start/end of the graph? Are you looking for exactly n length paths or up to n length paths?

Comment: @twain249 I'm not sure what you mean by start/end, but it's up to n length

Comment: If you know the neighbors of the nodes, just do a breadth first search till n.

Comment: I mean is there a node you are starting at and/or ending at or is it from any node to any other node.

Comment: @twain249 It's from any node to any other node

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: Like @noMAD said a Breadth First Search (from every node) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search bounding to the size n should work.

Comment: I mean can you write code that traverses the graph in depth until there's no adjacent vertices that you haven't visited at the current vertex, and print the path that lead you there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do a [depth-limited traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-limited_search) of the graph. This is just like depth-first search, except in the recursive step, you also add a variable called `depth` which is incremented every time you go down a depth. Then simply stop recursing once you've hit the desired depth.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an extra variable called `visited` in every node.
2. Do a breadth first search using a `Queue` and use the `visited` to prevent from forming a loop.
3. Do it for length `n`.

Comment: If I wanted the loops as well, could I just remove that second step? I want all paths including those that have loops.

Comment: Well, that will not work. If you are going to remove the `visited` then your code might never end as every node will keep communicating to its neighbors. So, what exactly do you mean by if you want the loops?

Comment: Well let's say A is adjacent to B, and there are no other nodes named A or B. I'd want A-B-A-B-A to be printed out as a valid path. Note that we're going up to a certain amount of iterations..

Comment: Of-course you can do that, but you will have to do some extra work cause your algorithm should have a termination condition. Can you think of a way to terminate your loop? ;-)

Comment: @varatis Protip: Having pointers inside each node to tell you where the node it came from really helps when you need to count things. It's not strictly neccesary, but I like doing it :D